# Does anyone have code examples of the WPF Datagrid working in a MVVM pattern?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, mvvm

I got the following example of a [WPF DataGrid](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=25047) bound to a ViewModel in a MVVM pattern, but it is read-only:

[MVVM example which has buttons that switch the data in the ViewModel](http://www.tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=180)

I tried to extend it so that the DataGrid was bound to an *observable collection of ViewModels* so that editing cells would fire OnPropertyChanged events on the appropriate ViewModels but couldn't get it to work the way I wanted.

Does anyone know of a code example that does this, i.e. **binding the DataGrid not to a collection of ViewModels with OnPropertyChanged properties and Delegate Commands**, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jaime Rodriguez and Karl Schifflett are doing a MVVM training roadshow. They have developed a demo application (which uses a datagrid) maybe you want to look into that applicatoin as well as the docs...

http://blogs.msdn.com/jaimer/archive/2009/02/10/m-v-vm-training-day-sample-application-and-decks.aspx